# iPod nano 7th generation app development

Tags: ipod-nano

What programming language does the iPod nano 7th generation use? I would like to develop an app for my own iPod nano 7th generation.

Answer (score 1):

The iPod nano uses a custom OS for which Apple has not made any documentation available, nor is there any way to load apps onto a nano. Only apps developed by Apple are available on the nano.